# two commands in a loop

Tags: python, string, loops

I started a loop and want to execute two commands, but only the last command is executed. What do I need to do that both commands will be executed?

```
import re
import string
from string import punctuation
doc_a = "Brocolli is good to eat. My brother likes to eat good brocolli, but not my mother."
doc_b = "My mother spends a lot of time driving my brother around to baseball practice."
doc_c = "Some health experts suggest that driving may cause increased tension and blood pressure."
doc_d = "I often feel pressure to perform well at school, but my mother never seems to drive my brother to do better."
doc_e = "Health professionals say that brocolli is good for your health."
doc_set = [doc_a, doc_b, doc_c, doc_d, doc_e]

for i in doc_set:

    doc_set = re.sub(r'\d+', '', i)


    doc_set = "".join(l for l in i if l not in string.punctuation)


print(doc_set)
```

Comment: Why do you assign  the `re.sub` result to `doc_set`? `re.sub` is modifying only one element of the list.

Comment: you overwrite result of first

Comment: Do `i = re.sub(r'\d+', '', i)` instead.

Comment: What is your desired final output? Remove punctuation?

Comment: i need to things: one command which deletes all digits (i know that in the text are no digits... i use another text)

Comment: @L3viathan yeah it worked! thanks a lot! all this is pretty new for me :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import re
import string
from string import punctuation
doc_a = "Brocolli is good to eat. My brother likes to eat good brocolli, but not my mother."
doc_b = "My mother spends a lot of time driving my brother around to baseball practice."
doc_c = "Some health experts suggest that driving may cause increased tension and blood pressure."
doc_d = "I often feel pressure to perform well at school, but my mother never seems to drive my brother to do better."
doc_e = "Health professionals say that brocolli is good for your health."
doc_set = [doc_a, doc_b, doc_c, doc_d, doc_e]

new_doc_set = []
for i in doc_set:
    i = re.sub(r'\d+', '', i)
    i = "".join(l for l in i if l not in string.punctuation)
    new_doc_set.append(i)

print(new_doc_set)
```